# Httpclient not works in release mode but works in debug mode in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Httpclient not works in release mode but works in debug mode in xamarin android. I tried restsharp also , but no luck

Below is the code that i tried

```
LoginViewModel Login = new LoginViewModel();
                Login.Username = "admin@gmail.com";
                Login.Password = "111111";
                Login.Usertype = "D";

                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Login);
                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://api.confervo.com/api/Account/Login", content);
                Toast.MakeText(this, response.Content + "", ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

Comment: You need to be sure you have INTERNET_PERMISSIONS enabled in your manifest file.  Debug mode will do this for you automatically, release will not.

Comment: if you are sending user names and passwords the call should use https not http

Comment: @KenTucker And even more so when you is connecting to a heathcare system (https://confervo.com) with your medical history :-/

Comment: @Jason its working with internet permissions, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and fixed with below code , Hope this will help you

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28"> 
... 
</application>
```